# Image acquisition in MATLAB at specified frame rate and save images as TIFF files on hard disk

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, camera, tiff

I am trying to acquire images with MATLAB controlling a Point Grey Grasshopper3 (USB3) camera (Model GS3-U3-41C6NIR-C). I need to acquire images at a defined frame rate (e.g. 12 FPS) for a duration of 80 seconds and safe the images on the hard disk of my computer in TIFF format (grayscale). I have the 'pointgrey' and 'winvideo' adaptors installed and the latest version of Matlab and the Image Acquisition Toolbox. (As OS, I use Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.)

```
>> imaqhwinfo

ans = 

    InstalledAdaptors: {'pointgrey'  'winvideo'}
        MATLABVersion: '8.3 (R2014a)'
          ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
       ToolboxVersion: '4.7 (R2014a)'
```

- How can I set the frame rate at 12 frames per second (or a similar value)?
- How can I store the acquired images on my HD as TIFF (grayscale) files? So far, I was only able to store images as AVI-files and then subsequently transform into .tif files.

Can anyone help me on this? Your help is highly appreciated!!

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hi Ghaul, thanks for asking! I just edited my original quesiton to make the problem clearer. The problem is that I have not ben able to store the acquired images on my HD as tif (grayscale) files. Also, I am struggling with setting a defined frame rate (12 fps). I would appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webcam has a defined set of framerates that you can choose from, you can't set it to any random frame rate you want. You can find the set of frame rates and change them by using the function `getselectedsource()` with your video object as input.

```
 src = getselectedsource(vid)

  Display Summary for Video Source Object:

  Index:   SourceName:   Selected:
  1        'input1'      'on'
```

The structure `src` now contains and controls many of the webcam properties, frame rate among them. Use the function `propinfo()` to see the current and available frame rates.

```
propinfo(src,'FrameRate')

ans = 

           Type: 'string'
     Constraint: 'enum'
ConstraintValue: {'30.0000'  '15.0000'}
   DefaultValue: '30.0000'
       ReadOnly: 'whileRunning'
 DeviceSpecific: 1
```

For my webcam I have two options, a framerate of 30 or 15. To change the frame rate do:

```
set(src, 'FrameRate','15');
```

To test the frame rate we can acquire some images and record the rate

```
vid.FramesPerTrigger = 50;
set(src, 'FrameRate','30')
start(vid); [frames, timeStamp] = getdata(vid);
1/mean(diff(timeStamp))

ans =

   29.1797

set(src, 'FrameRate','15')
start(vid); [frames, timeStamp] = getdata(vid);
1/mean(diff(timeStamp))

ans =

   15.0109
```

To save the images as .tiff use the `imwrite()` function while looping over the frames and use `sprintf()` to avoid overwriting the images.

```
for ii=1:size(frames,4)
     imwrite(frames(:,:,:,ii),sprintf('web%i.tiff',ii));
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ghaul! I highly appreciate your help! Your code works great. For larger numbers of FramesPerTrigger (I will eventually need around 1000), MATLAB however returns a message in the command window stating "Unable to allocate memory for an incoming image frame. Use IMAQMEM to modify your frame memory limit." As a consequence, GETDATA timed out before FRAMES were available. I was wondering how one could solve that memory problem. (My actual frame rate is 11.99 fps).

Comment: @ron767 No problem. Memory problems are often tricky and I'm no expert, but you could try reducing the resolution of the images you are capturing. If that doesn't work I would suggest that you post another question so that more people will see the problem.