# MATLAB: webcam video acquisition

Tags: matlab, video-capture

The [Logitech C910 webcam spec](https://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/hd-pro-webcam-c910/specs) indicates image and **video** capture.  Because image and video capture are listed separately, I am assuming that they are encoded and sent differently: effectively forming two different 'channels' to select from.  If this understanding is incorrect, please respond with an explanation of the true nature.

This reference indicates [a maximum frame-rate of 15](http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Logitech_HD_Pro_Webcam_C910) because of windows.

My search returned webcam video acquisition that comprises [a series of time lapsed images 'stitched' together](https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/usbwebcams/ug/logging-video-to-disk.html)

```
% Connect to the webcam.
cam = webcam

% Open Video File
vidWriter = VideoWriter('frames.avi');
open(vidWriter);

% Write images file
for index = 1:20
    % Acquire frame for processing
    img = snapshot(cam);
    % Write frame to video
    writeVideo(vidWriter,img);
end

%Close file and cam
close(vidWriter);
clear cam
```

MATLAB has captured successfully images with the C910.

## Question

If possible within MATLAB, how does one configure the webcam's **video* frame rate and save the video stream to .avi or the like? (not writing still images to video file as depicted above).

Perhaps someone with experience or sharper Google skills can provide an example of bridging the webcam's **video** (vs the image) stream into MATLAB. Any example that can be tested is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [In Matlab, writing images to AVI without displaying using VideoWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25200390/2723405) or [Image acquisition in MATLAB at specified frame rate and save images as TIFF files on hard disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13719138/2723405)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to 'jumpstart' or accelerate newbie familiarity is with the [image acquisition tool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/the-image-acquisition-tool-desktop.html):

```
imaqtool
```

The tool seems to be GUI wrapper that reduces the command-line syntax to a GUI.  Note that the bottom right panel shows the command line equivalent of a GUI interaction.

Configurable video capture paramaters comprise:

1. Resolution & ROI (Region of Interest)
2. Frame Rate
3. Video type (.avi .mp4) etc.

[image]